# syncfusion_flutter_pdf - unicode print not support properly

Tags: flutter, pdf, syncfusion

my text "இருக்கும்" but pdf output wrong. i used tamil fonts, google fonts, tried most of the fonts.

```
page.graphics.drawString(
    "இருக்கும்", await fontData(25, false),
    brush: PdfBrushes.white,
    bounds: Rect.fromLTWH(25, 0, pageSize.width - 115, 75),
    format: PdfStringFormat(lineAlignment: PdfVerticalAlignment.middle));

Future<PdfFont> fontData(double fontSize, bool isBold) async{
    final data = await rootBundle.load('fonts/akshar.ttf');
    final  dataInt = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes,data.lengthInBytes);
    final  PdfFont  font  =  PdfTrueTypeFont(dataInt, fontSize, style: isBold ?    PdfFontStyle.bold : PdfFontStyle.regular);
    return font;
  }
```

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.